# what is the basis of percent values for svg stroke-dashoffset

Tags: css, svg

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dashoffset

According to the link above, the stroke-dashoffset css property accepts percents.

What is the value that the percent is a percent of?

I expected it to the be the total length of the path. But in some experimentation that doesn't seem to be the case.

Here I try to animate from 0% to 100%...

```
.circles {
    stroke-dasharray: 50%;
    animation-name: dashingRotation;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes dashingRotation {
    0%     {stroke-dashoffset: 0%;}
    50%    {stroke-dashoffset: 100%;}
    100%   {stroke-dashoffset: 100%}
}
```

full code: https://jsfiddle.net/tssn40yL/

... but the dashes do not take up half the circles and the animation does not go all the way around.

So what do does that percent reference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#StrokeProperties)

> If a [`<percentage>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#DataTypePercentage) is used, the value represents a percentage of the current viewport (see [Units](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#Units)).
> ... The percentage is calculated as the specified percentage of sqrt((actual-width)**2 + (actual-height)**2))/sqrt(2).