# Svg line half solid, half dashed

Tags: css, svg

I have an inline SVG object, and some lines in it. I am trying to paint half of the line solid and the other half dashed.

```html
  
<svg height="30" width="300">
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4">
    <line stroke-dasharray="50%,1%,1%,1%" x1="10" x2="280" y1="10" y2="10" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: `stroke-dasharray: 135` ?

Comment: When you use `%` in your `stroke-dasharray` property, it will [take a value relative to the current viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635479/what-is-the-basis-of-percent-values-for-svg-stroke-dashoffset): not relative to the length of the line/path. If you want the line to be 50% filled, then you will need to compute the path length in JS and then set the attribute value to half that value.

Comment: Not many people are familiar with the pathLength attribute, but this is the perfect use case for using it (Danny's answer below) -- which avoids having to use JS or use two lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Put a `pathLength="100"` on the `line` so the **total** length is *calculated* as **100 *units***
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength
- set the `stroke-dasharray` ***units*** to the pattern you want:

  [image]

```html
<svg>
    <line pathLength="100" stroke-dasharray="50,2,5,2,5,2,5,2,5,2,5,2,5" 
          stroke="black" stroke-width="4"
          x1="10" x2="280" y1="10" y2="10" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Unit logic have much for use in my case, so I'll accept this one. Much appreciated.

Comment: Unit logic is always better than hard-coding... unless you don't know ``pathLength`` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman For six dashes, you use six pairs (2,5) of stroke-dasharray attributes. For a thousand dashes, would you write code with a thousand pairs of attributes (2,5) ?

Comment: I would use a Web Component to create the SVG: ``"2,5".repeat(1000)``

Answer (score 7):

The simplest would be to use 2 line objects. One to make the solid line and another for the dashed line. Here is an example :

```html
<svg height="30" width="300">
  <g fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4">
    <line x1="10" x2="150" y1="10" y2="10" />
    <line stroke-dasharray="5,5" x1="150" x2="280" y1="10" y2="10" />    
  </g>
</svg>
```

The [stroke-dasharray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) property will repeat itself indefinitely so if the "pattern" you enter doesn't last until the end of the line, it will use the first value again and repeat the pattern.
You can see that in your example the long dash (50% value) repeats itself 3 times with 3 small dashes (1% values) in between (2 empty and one solid).

Comment: Thank you for this right answer, but I don't have luxury to add another line. Much appreciated.

Comment: Well hopefully you get a better understanding about svg and `stroke-dasharray`. Have fun SVGing !